# res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'mapv02.html'));

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

mapv02.html is sending rigthly,but the '.js' in mapv01.html can not be found!

//routes/restapi.js

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'mapv02.html'));
```

//public/mapv02.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

Pass the name of the directory that contains the static assets to the express.static middleware function to start serving the files directly.

**Example:-** Use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
```

After this your script will be loaded successfully.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

For more reference see this link - http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

*Hope this will help to solve your query !!*

Comment: That is great.Thanks

Comment: Could you include full code?