# How can I serve mp3 file on node js?

Tags: node.js, express, mp3

I am building simple web app that if the user press button, it will make sound(mp3 file in the server side).

```
//html file
<script>
  function playSound () {
    document.getElementById('play').play();
  }
</script>
<body>
    <audio id='play', src='http://127.0.0.1:1337/', type='audio/mpeg'
       <button onclick='playSound()' class='btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-lg'>
          <i class='fa fa-5x fa-fire'>
</body>


//app.js
app.get('/music.mp3', function(req, res){
  ms.pipe(req, res, "/music.mp3");
});
```

It works if I insert online source in `audio` attribute, but it does not serve my local server file. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, audio, use the `express.static` built-in middleware function in Express.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I've already answered such type of question. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908392/res-sendfilepath-join-dirname-public-mapv02-html/36910476#36910476)

Comment: Thank you, I already figured out. But wish I could have your answer earlier