# Get mp3 file from node to react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, audio, mp3

I have two folders for the server (http: // loсalhost: 3000 node) and the client (http: // loсalhost: 3001 reactjs).

[image]
I have mp3 files on the server, I want to transfer them to the client, how can this be done? What should be the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [How can I serve mp3 file on node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957959/how-can-i-serve-mp3-file-on-node-js)

You can serve the mp3 file via a web service and use that api url in the react player.